# How to fix Run-time error '7' out of memory, which persists even after saving, closing, restarting computer

Tags: excel, vba, memory, out-of-memory, out

My Excel VBA macro produces "Run-time error '7': Out of memory"

The Excel document has a list of 5,500 csv documents in one sheet. The Macro goes through this list and, for each: a) puts their info into a consolidated output sheet; b) adds some formulas; and c) goes on to the next file.

After completing about 3,000 of them, the script hit the Out of memory error.

The main issue is that this problem persists after saving the file, closing Excel completely, re-opening Excel, and even restarting the computer. I also used Paste-Special to get rid of all formulas and replace with values. I also switched to Manual calculations.

I would like to find a way to prevent this error from occurring. At a minimum, if it occurs, I would like to be able to save, close, and re-open the file and keep going through the list 3,000 entries at a time.

I've read through all the previous questions and answers about Out of Memory errors, but none seem to have the issue persist after closing and reopening.

I am posting the relevant part of my code below. Debugger shows that the error occurred on the line: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False. I am running Windows 10, Excel 2007. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
Sub test()

Dim filename As String
Dim outputsheet As String
Dim output_lastrow As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False

For rep = 2 To 5502
    filename = Sheets("Import Files").Range("A" & rep).Value ‘this takes the form of C:\Users\...\filename1.csv
    outputsheet = "Summary"
    output_lastrow = Sheets(outputsheet).Range("D999999").End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + filename, Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range("$A" & output_lastrow + 2))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

        output_lastrow = Sheets(outputsheet).Range("D999999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets(outputsheet).Range("A" & output_lastrow).Value = "Change"
        Sheets(outputsheet).Range("B" & output_lastrow).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        Sheets(outputsheet).Range("C" & output_lastrow).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        Sheets(outputsheet).Range("C" & output_lastrow).AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & output_lastrow & ":FP" & output_lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

    End If

    Dim wbconnection As WorkbookConnection
    For Each wbconnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        If InStr(filename, wbconnection.Name) > 0 Then
            wbconnection.Delete
        End If
    Next wbconnection

Next rep
```

Comment: So you're adding 5501 QueryTables to the worksheet and you're surprised that you're running out of memory? Do you need all of them to be QueryTables, or are you just after the data?

Comment: I’m just after the data. If you can suggest a less memory-intensive way of bringing in the data from the csv files, that would be perfect! Note that, for what it’s worth, I’ve tried deleting the connections as I go with that last block of code.

Comment: A CSV file can just be opened as Ready Only with `Workbooks.Open`, then copy the data over and close it again.  Saving the workbook running the Macro every so often also helps to "clear down" some of the data that Excel decides it no longer needs to store for recovery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can just open a CSV file with `Workbooks.Open` in Ready-Only mode, and then copy the data like you would from a normal worksheet, try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim outputsheet As String
    Dim output_lastrow As Integer
    Dim wbCSV AS Workbook

    outputsheet = "Summary"

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For rep = 2 To 5502
        filename = Sheets("Import Files").Cells(rep, 1).Value ‘this takes the form of C:\Users\...\filename1.csv
        output_lastrow = Sheets(outputsheet).Cells(Sheets(outputsheet).Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        'Open CSV File
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        'Copy data to outputsheet
        wbCSV.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outputsheet).Cells(output_lastrow + 1, 1)

        'Close CSV File
        wbCSV.Close False
        Set wbCSV = Nothing
    Next rep

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you store `rep` somewhere in the Workbook, and save it every so often (`ThisWorkbook.Save`) then even if it does crash, you can just resume your loop from the last point you saved